# Perl apache filter validate the header in HTTP request

Tags: perl, apache, http

i want to write an apache filter written in perl that checks the request in input validating it only if there are some particular datas in the header otherwise it returns 401 Forbidden.

Anyone can please help me providing a skeleton of such a filter, I'm trying to read the official documentation but I can't figure out how to the skeleton of the script.

Thanks in advance.
Andrea

Answer (score 1, accepted):

That's not a filter, this word has a specific different meaning in the context of Apache httpd.

You want to write a handler, see chapter [*Handler Modules* in *Getting Your Feet Wet with mod_perl*](http://perl.apache.org/docs/2.0/user/intro/start_fast.html#Handler_Modules). To inspect headers, call the [`headers_in` method from `Apache2::RequestRec`](http://p3rl.org/Apache2%3a%3aRequestRec#headers_in).

Read the whole [manual](http://modperl2book.org/) and [documentation](http://perl.apache.org/docs/2.0/) already, you can easily answer yourself a simple question like this.

Comment: I'll check the documentation and if I'll have some issues again will be back to you :-) with more details